# MySQL: modify query with Inner Join on multiple tables while retaining column order

Tags: mysql, join

a client has asked me to modify the data retrieved from their database to their dashboard.  the method they use simply loops over a returned object and spits out the table.  what i have to do is now rework the original query to accomodate the desired changes, ***but*** must still conform to the existing method of table creation. the original query simply pulled ID numbers from one table thusly:

```sql
SELECT id, name, assetID, contractorID, dateLastServiced FROM reports WHERE staffID = <some#>;
```

what the client now wants is to replace the `assetID` and `contractorID` with the `assetName` and `contractorName` from their respective tables *BUT* the current order of columns **MUST** be maintained.

i'm not sure how to write the query for this and where to put the INNER JOIN statments to accomplish this. i'd rather not do the clunky get-separate-stuff-from-three-tables-and-then-make-object thing.

this is what i have so far, but i'm stuck:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.name,
INNER JOIN al.assetName FROM asset_list "al" WHERE al.id = r.assetID,
INNER JOIN cl.contractorName FROM cont_list "cl" WHERE cl.id = r.contractorID,
r.dateLastServiced FROM reports "r" WHERE r.staffID = <some#>;
```

while this makes a logical sense, it isn't getting me what i need.  what do i need to change?

if, as an added bonus, you could show me how to return the column names AS something readable, eg. contractorName AS "Contractor Name" in this mix, that would be awesome.  i don't think there is a way to smash this all together, but then again, i'm here for help, right?

**EDIT:** i was going to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.name, al.assetName, cl.contractorName, r.dateLastServiced
FROM reports "r", asset_list "al', cont_list "cl" 
WHERE al.id = r.assetID AND cl.id = r.contractorID AND r.staffID = <some#>
```

but i read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and wasn't sure if it was the right way to go...

Comment: With out data it is difficult so see please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please use standard punctuation. Please format code reasonably. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
    r.id
    ,r.name
    ,al.assetName
    ,cl.contractorName
    ,r.dateLastServiced
from 
    (select * from reports where r.staffID = <someid>) r 
    JOIN asset_list al on r.assetID = al.id
    JOIN cont_list cl on r.contractorID = c.id;
```

Comment: okay.  that works perfectly!  thank you!  :)  may i ask why `JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? shorthand or is there an efficiency element there?  again, thank you!  this helped click a lot of `JOIN` related things into place for me.

Comment: INNER JOIN - JOIN they both are same.

Comment: also: can i do `SELECT id, name, dateLastServiced FROM reports...` instead of `SELECT *...` or will that not matter performance-wise?

Comment: Since i didn't know what are the columns you need I used * in sub query.

You can choose relevant columns in sub query which will be efficient than using *

Comment: (select id,name,datelastserviced,assetid,contractorid  from reports) r

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. 